# What Hot Shoe Accessories are Available for a Canon T3 / EOS 1100D?

Tags: canon-1100d, hotshoe

Specifically, what hot shoe accessories are available for the T3 / 1100D that use the hot shoe electronics to communicate with the camera (besides flashes)?

Comment: Does it have to be two-way communication, or would reacting to flash signal suffice?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you are looking for. There are only a few main things that I commonly see hot shoes being used for these days:

- Flash Units
- Flash Cords
- Bubble levels
- Video Lights
- Microphones
- GPS Units

In the past I have seen them used for a few other things, but this is much less common:

- Special viewfinder type units
- Light meters

Since you don't specify any particular need, that is about all I can tell you:)

Comment: Considering the Canon hot-shoe is so standard, it would have  been easier to list those which it does not support ;)

Comment: Thanks.  Specifically I was wondering if any of those beyond the flash units were compatible with the T3 / 1100D.

Comment: @ChuckC. - Sure any of the items in the first list would work. They all can work independently of the camera actually, depending on which model and features you are looking for. It might be better to ask for compatibility with a specific accessory rather then asking this wide open question.

Comment: Gotcha.  I should have worded by question differently.  What I meant was, what hot shoe accessories are available for the T3 / 1100D that use the hot shoe electronics to communicate with the camera.  The bubble level would not.  The flash would.  I do not believe there is a GPS or microphone available for the camera that can communicate via the hot shoe.  I updated the question.